# Android - problem with Math.atan2

Tags: java, android, andengine

So in my android game I'm making with andengine, I have it set up so as I touch and drag the player sprite, it continously rotates so that the character is always facing the direction it is traveling.

```
public class Player extends AnimatedSprite {
private float lastX = Game.centerX;
private float lastY = Game.centerY;
private static int angle = 0;

// ...

@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent sceneTouchEvent, final float touchAreaLocalX, final float touchAreaLocalY) {
    Body body = OrbCatch.physicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findBodyByShape(this);
    if (sceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        float currentX = sceneTouchEvent.getX();
        float currentY = sceneTouchEvent.getY();
        angle = (int) (Math.atan2(currentY - lastY, currentX - lastX) * 180 / Math.PI);
        lastX = currentX;
        lastY = currentY;
    }
    body.setTransform(new Vector2(sceneTouchEvent.getX(),sceneTouchEvent.getY() )
    .mul(1/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT),angle);
    return true;
}

}
```

The key line is this:

```
angle = (int) (Math.atan2(currentY - lastY, currentX - lastX) * 180 / Math.PI)
```

It takes the last known coordinates and the current coordinates, calculates the angle between them, and converts it from radians to degrees. Well, this was all working fine yesterday, but despite changing none of this code today it's behaving strangely. The sprite's orientation changes erratically, with no apparent pattern. If I move it in a straight path, it continuously alternates between 2 or 3 distinctly different angles(usually one of them is the correct one).

edit: solved, see below

Comment: Is there any chance your `Body` is being accessed by multiple threads concurrently?

Comment: ... the result for your dataset is 90° on my system ...!?

Comment: I'm with sje397; my guess is that `lastX` and `lastY` are changing out from under you.

Comment: No, that's the only thread where it's being accessed. And lastX/lastY are never touched or even read anywhere else.

Comment: @Andreas: 90 is the correct answer. You'll notice that Wolfram's `tan-1` function takes `(x, y)`, while Java's takes `(y, x)`, giving you a 90-degree difference.

Comment: Are you saying that `Math.atan2(1, 0)` is giving you 2.356 instead of 1.571?

Comment: Okay, nevermind about atan2, it's working correctly. Not only did I not notice that wolfram did it with x,y instead of y,x, but I also forgot that I had been adding 45 to angle(I left that part out of the question). So the problem isn't in the math.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Body.setTransform angle parameter takes values in radians, not degrees. Andengine is so poorly documented...

Answer (score 0):

```
math.todegree(math.atan(....))....
```

You should use `toDegree()`.